# Google Apps Script modal window HTML - link's href issue

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-apps-script

I am facing some strange issue with Google Apps Script modal window HTML parsing mechanism.

Minimal reproduceable example:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html/test');

var html = template.evaluate().setWidth(1920).setHeight(1080);
ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Test');
```

`html/test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://test.com/#gid=0&range=A1:B1" target="_blank">https://test.com/#gid=0&range=A1:B1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output in modal window: link that points to `https://test.com/#gid=0&range=A1:B1`.

Actual link unexpectedly points to different URL: `https://test.com/#gid=0%E2%A6%A5=A1:B1`.

Google Chrome developer tools shows next link's HTML:

```
<a href="https://test.com/#gid=0⦥=A1:B1" target="_blank">https://test.com/#gid=0&amp;range=A1:B1</a>
```

Why link's `href` gets overwritten? Is there anything can be done to make Google Apps Script display links as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

gs:

```
function displayMyDialog() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah3');//my html file name
  var html = template.evaluate().setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);//change to fit my window
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Test');
}
```

Replace `&` with `&amp;`

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://test.com/#gid=0&amp;range=A1:B1" target="_blank">https://test.com/#gid=0&amp;range=A1:B1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

honestly I can't remember where I learned this.

Comment: Thanks, it helped indeed. Assuming initial behaviour is Apps Script's bug, reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162919947

Comment: @Kos Personally, I don't see how it would be considered an apps script bug. It's just boils down how to knowing to url encode html.

Comment: then, it is definitely most creative way to encode html attributes I ever seen, hats off to apps script team. Hopefully one day we'll see decoder for that _encoded_ output)

Comment: I learned it a long time ago. Way before apps script.